# How to integrate CAS(single sign on) rest authenticate url with angular 4

Tags: angular, spring-boot, single-sign-on, cas

we have  spring boot application for back end api
we have  angular 4 for front end
we are using CAS server for authentication(single sign on).
how to authenticate CAs server(single sign on) in Angular 4 application as well we need to check every api has valid CAS token(TGT token).

Comment: If you authenticated backend why would you need to authenticate frontend?

Comment: 1)Login page is angular 4 so we don't want to show login page if already i have authenticate with CAS server  .do you have any example code angular 4 with spring boot

Comment: And that should be done only by backend, no need to introduce sso to frontend

Comment: Login page should be Backend right?

Comment: Login page is login page, it is up to backend to decide if frontend should display such page or not.